# Different menus for different user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to display two different menus depending on the user role.

I have setup a new role called 'clients' using this code (in functions.php):

```
add_role( 'client', 'Client', array(
    'read' => true,
 ) 
);
```

and I have two different menus using this code (in functions.php):

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
  'client-navigation' => __( 'Client Navigation' ),
  'staff-navigation' => __( 'Staff Navigation' ),

    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

here is the code which I'm trying to use to call either Client Navigation or Staff Navigation (in header.php):

```
<?php
        if (current_user_can('client')){
            //menu for client role
             wp_nav_menu( array('theme-location' => 'client-navigation' ));

        }else{
            //default menu
             wp_nav_menu( array('theme-location' => 'staff-navigation' ));
        }
?>
```

I've also tried adding 'echo' before wp_nav_menu and changing `theme-location` to `menu` and used the menu name, but it always shows `staff-navigation` menu.

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working? Are you seeing no menus? The same menu both times? Do you have menu items added to both menus? Are you logged in as a client? I believe `current_user_can` accepts a capability not a role.

Comment: No it always shows staff-navigation menu, I have different links in each menu, Im using two browsers (1 admin login and 1 client login) to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [`current_user_can`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can), you should add your own [custom capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap).

Without doing that, as you're looking for the role, the following function, adapted [from here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-users-role) does the job:

```
function check_for_clients() {
    global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    return ($user_role == 'client');
}
```

And then in your header.php file (note that you have a [typo in `theme_location`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)):

```
if ( check_for_clients() ){
     wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'client-navigation' ));

} else {
     wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'staff-navigation' ));
}
```

Comment: thanks b, this correctly checks if the user is a client now but it is still loading the same menu for both clients and staff members.

Comment: Nick, it was a typo in your code, see updated answer.